# Ignore code evaluation output in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is it possible to set a header setting in a `org` file to indicate that when I eval any source code block in the file it shouldn't change the file contents? I don't want that default `#+RESULTS:` block that's added by default below the code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this at the top of the file:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args    :results silent
```

From [the documentation on using header arguments](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!