# Execute source block without output

Tags: org-babel

I use the package `ryo-modal-mode` and for the key assignment I have long code blocks in an org-file.

If I execute the code block I get a very long table under `#+RESULTS`. Is it possible to execute a block without result, or disable output?

Before I used `M-x eval-region`. Hitting `C-c C-c` would be easier, if there wasn't the long results table.

Comment: You could use the [header argument `:results silent`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html).

Comment: Yes. This works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [header argument `:results silent`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) to suppress the `#+RETULTS:` output of a single source block. With the header argument, the results are shown in the message buffer instead.

Minimal working example:

```el
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
"This string goes to the message buffer instead of popping up below the source block."
#+END_SRC
```

How you can suppress the insertion of the results for all source blocks of an org file is described in [the answer to another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34233/ignore-code-evaluation-output-in-org-mode).